# Querying multiple rows of an XML column to extract child nodes into multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

In SQL server, I have a table with an XML column, and from each XML, I have  nodes under a parent  node and I want to select each value in the  node into a separate row for each XML.

How do I accomplish that?

Below is a sample of how the table looks:

```
Name    | Message
John    | <User><Data><Valuelist><Value>123</Value><Value>456</Value><Value>789</Value><Value>654</Value></ValueList></Data></User>
Jack    | <User><Data><ValueList><Value>555</Value><Value>455</Value></ValueList></Data></User>
Jane    | <User><Data><Valuelist><Value>576</Value><Value>854</Value><Value>933</Value></ValueList></Data></User>
```

Below is a sample XML from the Message column I'm trying to query from, for better clarity:

```
<User>
     <Data>
          <ValueList>
              <Value>123</Value>
              <Value>456</Value>
              <Value>789</Value>
              <Value>654</Value>
          </ValueList>
     </Data>
</User>
```

And below is what I expect to see in the result:

```
Name    | Values
John    | 123
John    | 456
John    | 789
John    | 654
Jack    | 555
Jack    | 455
Jane    | 576
Jane    | 854
Jane    | 933
```

I have been attempting to use the below query:

```
select t.Name, x.y.value('(Value)', 'nvarchar(10)') [Values]
from TABLE t
cross apply t.Message.nodes('//ValueList') as x(y)
```

But it gives me the below error:

> 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

I'm only able to select one of the values using:

```
select t.Name, x.y.value('(Value[1])', 'nvarchar(10)') [Values]
from TABLE t
cross apply t.Message.nodes('//ValueList') as x(y)
```

I have been googling around but couldn't quite find something for what I'm trying to do.

What should I do here?

My SQL server version is 2016 SP2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you need another `nodes` method against `x.y`? Without any sampel XML, and expected results, impossible to know.

Comment: My bad! Let me edit the post to include a sample XML.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Sorry! This is my first time posting to stackoverflow, and I'm still learning SQL.

Comment: No worries. Just copy ##1-4 to your question, and use them as section headers.

Comment: Seems that `//ValueList` should actually be `/User/Data/ValueList/Value` and then you need to get `text()` in your `value` method. (I would also use the alias `VL(V)` if I am honest, for `ValueList (Value)`.

Comment: @Larnu, I'm actually using aliases for my actual data-set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl table (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(20), Message XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (Name, Message) VALUES
('John', N'<User><Data><ValueList><Value>123</Value><Value>456</Value><Value>789</Value><Value>654</Value></ValueList></Data></User>'),
('Jack', N'<User><Data><ValueList><Value>555</Value><Value>455</Value></ValueList></Data></User>'),
('Jane', N'<User><Data><ValueList><Value>576</Value><Value>854</Value><Value>933</Value></ValueList></Data></User>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.ID, t.Name
    , c.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') AS [Values]
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY Message.nodes('/User/Data/ValueList/Value') as t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+------+--------+
| ID | Name | Values |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | John |    123 |
|  1 | John |    456 |
|  1 | John |    789 |
|  1 | John |    654 |
|  2 | Jack |    555 |
|  2 | Jack |    455 |
|  3 | Jane |    576 |
|  3 | Jane |    854 |
|  3 | Jane |    933 |
+----+------+--------+
```

Comment: Hello, could you please tell me how './text()' works here/point me to a resource about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is for performance reasons. You can see it yourself. Just copy the `SELECT` statement, and delete `/text(()`, and execute both SELECTs in one shot with the **Actual Execution Plan** on,. And compare Query cost relative to the batch.

Comment: Apologies for my delay in response, this works perfectly. Thanks a ton!